# C# Convert interfaces

Tags: c#

Cast a class to an interface is the same as convert a Class to another Class in C#?Does box or unboxing occurs in this process?

```
interface Area
{
   string TxtArea
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
}
```

Convert to it interface:

```
public void Test()

    {
       ExternArea extArea = new ExternArea();
       if(extArea is Area)
       {
         ((Area)extArea).TxtArea = "voila";
       }
    }
```

Comment: It is (IMHO) good practise to begin interface names with 'I'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `ExternArea` is a class rather than a value type (struct or enum), there's no boxing involved. Boxing only *ever* converts a value type to a reference type instance.

Note that using `as` is generally preferred though:

```
Area area = extArea as Area;
if (area != null)
{
    area.TxtArea = "voila";
}
```

Comment: Will firts line throws an exception if extArea doenst inherits Area interface?

Comment: @user No, area is set to null

Answer (score 2):

Boxing only occurs if you convert a *value type* (a struct or a number) to a *reference type* (`object` or an interface implemented by the `struct`)

Casting a reference type (an instance of a class) to a different reference type (a base class or an interface implemented by the class) does not involve boxing.

Even so, [you should not cast unnecessarily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx); instead, use the `as` keyword, like this:

```
Area area = extArea as Area;
if (area != null)
{
    area.TxtArea = "voila";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boxing and unboxing have to do with packaging a value type inside an object, so it can be used as a reference type (allocated on the heap). When you're unboxing, you're getting such a value back from the "box".  So no, this would not occur in this example.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `ExternArea` object in your code sample is a reference type, then - no - no boxing operations will be performed. Boxing and unboxing refers to operations undertaken when value types are converted into objects.

For more information, please see [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).